# Tasks by Planner and To Do is not picking up the name which are already created via api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Here, I am building the plan in Microsoft Teams Planner from my codebase using Microsoft API's

Also, we can create a plan from the UI which Microsoft provides.

So, the confusion here is, let say I create a new plan with the name **Plan** from my codebase. With that, I can still create the plan from **Tasks by Planner and To Do** tab UI with the same name as **Plan**.

[image]

Also, I create two plans with the case for example Tasks and tasks are considered as different.

[image]

So, the above is normal behaviour or something is wrong with my interpretation?

Comment: In your case, what is unique is the teams tab name. As for the plans, the title is not unique so you can have plans with the same name. If this answers you let me know so that I can post an answers.

Answer (score 0):

Plan names are not required to be unique within a team. We also don't require all plans to show up as tabs. Tab names however are unique. When you create a plan in the API, it is not automatically added as a tab. When you create a new plan from the UI by adding a tab, it creates a new plan and a new tab linked to that plan. If you use same names in both actions, you'll end up with 2 plans with the same name, and one tab that connects to the plan created with the tab. You can rename plans in the (API or Planner UI) to help users to differentiate them easier.